# timezone and time() issue, time now is less than time before

Tags: php, time, datetime-format

I am using wordpress where the defualt timezone is UTC, though I do not understand why this would make a difference because it is the same person that wants to update something on the website, and the time compared is for that person, in this case me.

So, I want to update my password, and when that happens a new datetime value is inserted in the appropriate table, and when I click the link in the email link that I receive, the page I go to makes a new time like so:

```
$time_now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$time_now = strtotime($time_now);
```

And before that I pull the appropriate value from the table and convert it to time like so:

```
$time_then = strtotime($time_then);
```

So even though it is ME doing all this from the same computer, I get a result where `$time_then` is BIGGER than `$time_now`.

The time seems to be off for like 2 hours, so I can add 2 hours to `$time_now`, but would that work the way it should for all people, regardless of their country?

And why is `$time_then` bigger than `$time_now` anyway?

**UPDATE:**

Just to make it clear, the time I insert into the DB is CORRECT, while the time I get with php on the page is wrong ( 1 hour less in my case ).

**UPDATE 2: code**

```
    foreach ($q as $key => $value) {
        $time_then = $value->req_date;
        $e = $value->email;
    }

    echo 'Time then normal: '.$time_then.'<br>';

    $time_then = strtotime($time_then);

    // check how much time has elapsed
    $time_now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    echo 'Time now normal: '.$time_now.'<br>';

    $time_now = strtotime($time_now);

    echo 'Time then: '.$time_then.'<br>';
    // echo 'Time now: '.$time_now.'<br>';
    $time_now = time();
    echo 'Time now: '.$time_now.'<br>';


    if ($time_now > $time_then) {
        echo 'Good <br>';
    } else {
        echo 'Abnormal <br>';
    }
```

So after I go to the link provided in the email ( after the req_date has been inserted into the DB ), I get for example the following shown on the page:

```
Time then normal: 2014-11-07 11:11:23
Time now normal: 2014-11-07 10:11:38
Time then: 1415358683
Time now: 1415355098
Abnormal
```

Comment: How and where do you set `$time_then`? Also, instead of doing a `date` call and the convert it to time, just call `time()` and get UNIX time instantly.

Comment: I get it from the database to which it was stored with NOW() function. I need that nice formatted date time as well, that is why I am converting it to time.

Comment: But you are overwriting `$time_now` with the timestamp. That doesn't make sense. Also, add the part about where you get `$time_then` to your question, and you might get an answer.

Comment: He means that you might as well have done `$time_now = time();` instead of those 2 lines where you convert the current time to a friendly format and then back to a timestamp, it's an unnecessary step

Comment: So are you able to confirm which time is the correct time? The one you insert into your database using `NOW()` or the time you get using PHP?

Comment: I know that Jonathon but that is beside the point, 2 lines or 1 line is irrelevant. The time I insert into DB is CORRECT, the time I get with PHP is off by 1 hour ( 1 hour less ).

Comment: Please provide a complete code sample **and values**. Output every relevant value and show us what is what at each stage.

Comment: This question is really hard to answer without testing the system, but my guess is that your webserver clock and dbserver clock are not the same.

Comment: @deceze I posted all the relevent stuff ( i believe )

Answer (score 0):

So after I go to the link provided in the email ( after the req_date has been inserted into the DB ), I get for example the following shown on the page:

$time_now = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
$time_now = strtotime($time_now);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).